# Объединение элементов списка с условием

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть список первый:

```
list1 = ['Первый элемент', 'Второй элемент']
```

И основной список

```
list2 = ['Апельсин', 'Яблоко', 'Первый элемент', 'Груша', 'Второй элемент', 'Персик', 'Мандарин', 'Первый элемент']
```

Необходимо проверить есть ли элемент списка list2 в list1, и если есть, то объединить его с предыдущим элементом.

То есть, должно получиться:

```
list3 = ['Апельсин', 'ЯблокоПервый элемент', 'ГрушаВторой элемент', 'Персик', 'МандаринПервый элемент']
```

Как это можно сделать?

Я пытался сделать так:

```
for i in list2:
 if i not in list1:                                                                
   list3.append(i)
 else:
   print(list2[list2.index(i)-1] + list1[list1.index(i)])
```

Comment: это просто цикл по "основному" списку. Что у вас не получается?

Comment: У меня почему-то всё с первым попавшимся элементом объединятся

Comment: приведите ваш код

Comment: дополнил свой вопрос

Comment: Если нужно объединить, то для чего там \n? И лучше в данном случае сразу в цикле работать с индексами, тогда не надо будет городить костыли типа list1[list1.index(i)], которые совсем не всегда работают так, как вам хочется.

Comment: это я делаю бота, просто для оформления в чате. Забыл убрать \n

Comment: Нужно добавить в вопрос условие - а предыдущий элемент удалить.

Comment: @A_Vaclav покажите?

Comment: Я имел ввиду описание, как вы задали вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list1 = ['Первый элемент', 'Второй элемент']
list2 = ['Апельсин', 'Яблоко', 'Первый элемент', 'Груша', 'Второй элемент', 
         'Персик', 'Мандарин', 'Первый элемент']
tmp = []
for i in range(len(list2)):
    if list2[i] in list1:
        tmp.append(list2[i - 1] + list2[i])
    elif list2[i + 1] in list1:
        tmp.append('')
    else:
        tmp.append(list2[i])
result = [x for x in tmp if x != '']
print(result)

>>>['Апельсин', 'ЯблокоПервый элемент', 'ГрушаВторой элемент', 'Персик', 'МандаринПервый элемент']
```

Comment: по идее надо бы это оформить в функцию, что бы "сборщик мусора" удалил из памяти промежуточные результаты.

Answer (score 2):

как вариант, можно воспользоваться встроенной функцией zip, как-то так:

```
list1 = ['Первый элемент', 'Второй элемент']
list2 = ['Апельсин', 'Яблоко', 'Первый элемент', 'Груша', 'Второй элемент', 
         'Персик', 'Мандарин', 'Первый элемент','кокос']
list3 = [i + j if j in list1 else i for i,j in zip(list2,list2[1:]+['']) if not i in list1]
```